# Two type attributes "button" and "submit" in one <button> tag in HTML

Tags: html

I want to create a button in HTML which has both type attributes `button` and `submit`. How to do that?

Here is a code snipet:

```
<html>
<body>
<p> This is a test code </p>
     <audio id = "song" src="./audio/A1.wav" controls></audio>

     <form>
     <input type="radio" id="happy" name="emotion" value="happy">
     <label >Happy</label><br/>
     <button type="button|submit" onclick="nextAudio()"> NEXT </button>
     </form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="audio.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Type `button` is used to change the audio from an array stored in the `javascript` file.

Type `submit` is used to send data of the radio button to the database.

This is not working. Please help !!!!!

Comment: Pretty sure you can only have one type. Why do you need multiple types? The Button is going to trigger onclick="nextAudio() when clicked on anyways?

Comment: You don't want this to submit, as a submit will reload the page and interrupt the audio. What you are looking for is an ajax call inside your nextAudio() function to submit the form data to the database. Check the search for how to read your form data in js and make ajax calls.

Comment: @rx2347 button type submit always reloads the page unless you add `event.preventDefault()` on click event. So the submit - reload has nothing to do in this. The best way to achieve this is via ajax call, add call on your `nextAudio()`

Comment: @AkhilAravind thats exactly what I wrote. Feel free to give it a like next time around.

Comment: @rx2347 thank you, will try that
can you recommend any code snippet which I can try

Comment: Sure, take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two types for one button element.

The [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-button-type) says:

> The type attribute controls the behavior of the button when it is activated.

It would be ambiguous to expect two different behaviours of one element.

As pointed in the comments, you can send an AJAX, without submitting the form and reloading the page.